# Who admits new Transifex Translators?

Tags: translation

CiviCRM's translations are managed on Transifex, I have been a coordinator of the German team for about two or three years. I noticed that new translators are admitted to the German language team regularly and I was wondering how that works.

I only know two other coordinators (there are six) and reached out to them but they don't do it either. I would love to be able to contact new translators before they actually translate strings in order to let them know about best practices.

So my question is: Who is the manager able to permit new translators on a Transifex team (particularly the German one)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Transifex has a setting to automatically accept new team members, but it is a global setting, not per language.

My recommendation would be to use the "reviewer" feature of CiviCRM. If you tag strings as reviewed, only reviewers can edit them. You can then more easily review strings that have been translated by new translators.

I agree, however, that it would be nice to have a better welcome process for translators. Currently the only help we have, is the text shown on the main [CiviCRM Transifex project page](https://www.transifex.com/civicrm/civicrm/), which says "help page" and leads to [Translator Resources](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Translator+resources).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The reviewer feature is nice but it often implies that you are fixing something that wouldn't necessarily have to be broken in the first place. We had a lot of trouble with incorrect translations lately and I think, many of the could have been prevented if new translators were advised on best practices. The wiki site has not been edited for years and (in regard to German) is not helpful at all. I am going to mark this question as answered but would love to continue the discussion elsewhere. Forum? Partnerlist? What do you (and others) think?

Comment: I agree, it's not an ideal situation, especially if you use l10nupdate or equivalent to auto-update translations. It would be great to have a better process in place. Could you post on the i18n forum, and send a link of that to the "new" civicrm-intl list (civicrm-intl@lists.civicrm.org or http://lists.civicrm.org/lists/info/civicrm-intl)?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - I just got out of my holiday break. I made a post in the CiviCRM Internationalization forum (hope that's the one you meant) and  I am going to send it out using the mailing list.

Comment: Time goes by and there are still many translations waiting for review. Any updates on this? Who is responsible for (German) review?